# C++ заполнение массива

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
  const int sz = 10;
  int arr[sz];
  int counter = 0; //счетчик для определения размера будущего массива
  ////////
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //заполняем исходный массив 
    arr[i] = rand() % 10;
  }
  ////////
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) { //подсчет количествва чисел больше 6
    if (arr[i] > 6) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  //////////
  int * Tarr = new int[counter]; // создание массива с нужным размером
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) { //цикл для заполнения второго массива. предполагается,что с его размером все ок
    if (arr[i] > 6) { //если значение больше то заполняем ячейку
      Tarr[i] = arr[i];
    }
  }
  //////////
  for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { //вывод второго массива

    std::cout << Tarr[i] << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << counter << std::endl;

  return 0;
};
```

Суть такова: имеется иниц. массив. Нужно создать другой массив который включает в себя числа из первого, но только с числами больше 6. Но на выходе получаю 4 числа: мусор; 7; мусор; мусор; Да там действительно 4 числа, и действительно 7 должна присутствовать на втором месте. но почему остальные 3 числа мусор?

Comment: Может есть другие способы отсечь от массива числа меньше 6?

Comment: А что вы там хотите увидеть? если в мусор переписываете только *одну* семерку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При копировании у вас должно быть **два** указателя. Один откуда копируем, а второй куда вставляем

```c
int to = 0;
//цикл для заполнения второго массива. предполагается,что с его размером все ок
for (int from = 0; from < sz; from++) {
  if (arr[from] > 6) { //если значение больше то заполняем ячейку
    Tarr[to++] = arr[from];
  }
}
```

Comment: Где сайз нового буффера? что делать если не хватит памяти? или останется кончик с мусором? счетчик записи? да и с указателями на прямую в С++ уже лет 5 не принято работать.

Comment: @Andrey Все в программе ТС. Я привел только исправленный участок. И где у меня прямая работа с указателями?

Comment: Голый массив уже указатель, есть std::array

Answer (score 0):

У Вас стоит метка вопроса С++. Давайте решим Вашу проблему в стиле С++.

Вам отлично подойдет алгоритм std::copy_if.
Предлагаю заменить массивы на вектора.
см. код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 4}; // Ваш массив я думаю вы вставите

    std::vector<int> v2{};

    std::copy_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v),  std::back_inserter(v2), [](const int i){return (i > 6);});

    for (const auto& val : v2) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```